# merging two or more node.js require modules into one namespace

Tags: node.js

Google Flatbuffers creates in (AMD?) module for each table that one wants. I have them all in one name space called PNTCI.

Right now, I am doing something ugly and non-intuitve to merge the name spaces together by doing successive includes to the PNTCI namespace like this:

```
const telem = require('../messages/Telemetry_generated').PNTCI
const PNTCI = Object.assign(telem, require('../messages/header_generated').PNTCI)
```

The again the reason is that the autogenerated require modules have a old fashioned format that looks like this for the Header_generated.js :

```
// automatically generated by the FlatBuffers compiler, do not modify

/**
 * @const
 * @namespace
 */
var PNTCI = PNTCI || {};

/**
 * Common header for all PNTCI message payloads
 *
 * @constructor
 */
```

and the end of the file looks like this:

```
/**
 * @param {flatbuffers.Builder} builder
 * @param {flatbuffers.Offset} offset
 */
PNTCI.Header.finishHeaderBuffer = function(builder, offset) {
  builder.finish(offset);
};

// Exports for Node.js and RequireJS
this.PNTCI = PNTCI;
```

and for Telemetry_generated.js

```
// automatically generated by the FlatBuffers compiler, do not modify

/**
 * @const
 * @namespace
 */
var PNTCI = PNTCI || {};

/**
 * @constructor
 */
PNTCI.PosVector = function() {
  /**
   * @type {flatbuffers.ByteBuffer}
   */
  this.bb = null;
```

and then the end of the file looks like this:

```
PNTCI.Telemetry.finishTelemetryBuffer = function(builder, offset) {
  builder.finish(offset);
};

// Exports for Node.js and RequireJS
this.PNTCI = PNTCI;
```

Comment: The code you provided doesn't contain modules at all. There's no export so it's unclear how you used `require` on them. Whatever the problem is, it's specific to Flatbuffers output.

Comment: true  @estus, they are not proper modules. But google puts code at the end that allows import by node.js and Require.js, I have now illustrated that code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of namespaces isn't idiomatic to Node.js because a module itself acts as a namespace, so the problem is specific to these particular modules.

It can be written shorter with object spread syntax:

```
const PNTCI = {
  ...require('../messages/Telemetry_generated').PNTCI,
  ...require('../messages/header_generated').PNTCI
};
```

Which is syntactic sugar for:

```
const PNTCI = Object.assign({},
  require('../messages/Telemetry_generated').PNTCI,
  require('../messages/header_generated').PNTCI
);
```

If these modules are constantly used together, it may be beneficial to re-export them as single module:

```
module.exports = {
  ...require('../messages/Telemetry_generated').PNTCI,
  ...require('../messages/header_generated').PNTCI
};
```

Since there's generally no need for namespaces in Node, merging modules under single `PNTCI` variable may be unneeded; modules could be imported separately to different variables. This makes the application more modular if only some of these modules are used in some places.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also iterate over `messages` dir contents if there's a bunch of them.